# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte / unexpected end of data

Tags: python, pyside2

I am trying to pass some functions from C++ to Python using the Qt library (Pyside2 in python). At the moment everything works correctly passing the code from one side to the other and adapting it to Python, but when I start treating images errors happen.

The only thing that I achieve is to correctly parse the shadows of the images, however, the inner part of the image (which would correspond to the rest of the colors is hollow).

I should get this

[image: Expected Image result]

but I get this instead

[image: This code Image result]

And every time I treat those bytes, the program crashes with the following errors.

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 0: invalid start byte
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Debugging the program I discovered that only the bytes that correspond to the colors crashes the program, making it impossible to know the RGBA of the pixel. The problem must be with the way I get GB and AR in Python, since the original C ++ program never had this problem in any of the pixels.

I am quite a newbie dealing with bytes and bytearrays. Do you think that I can be doing wrong to get GB and AR or what do you think?

Thank you all!

This is the original function in C++:

```
QImage ImageConverter::convertGBAR4444(QByteArray &array, int width, int height, int startByte)
/// GBAR = ARGB (endianness)
{
    qDebug() << "Opened GBAR4444 image.";
    QImage img(width, height, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    img.fill(Qt::transparent);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            uchar gb = array.at(startByte + y * 2 * width + x * 2);
            uchar ar = array.at(startByte + y * 2 * width + x * 2 + 1);
            uchar g = gb >> 4;
            uchar b = gb & 0xF;
            uchar a = ar >> 4;
            uchar r = ar & 0xF;
            img.setPixel(x, y, qRgba(r * 0x11, g * 0x11, b * 0x11, a * 0x11));
        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

And this is my code for the Python version of the project:

```
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage, qRgba, qRgb

def convertGBAR4444(array, width, height, startByte = 0):
    y = 0
    img = QImage(width, height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    img.fill(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0,0))
    while (y < height):
        x = 0
        while (x < width):
            gb = ord(array.at(startByte + y * 2 * width + x * 2))
            ar = ord(array.at(startByte + y * 2 * width + x * 2 + 1))
            g = gb >> 4
            b = gb & 0xF
            a = ar >> 4
            r = ar & 0xF
            img.setPixel(x, y, qRgba(r * 0x11, g * 0x11, b * 0x11, a * 0x11))
            x += 1
        y += 1
    return img
```

If you want to try it yourself this are the data you will need:

```
convertGBAR4444(data, 32, 32, 13)

data = b'\x01 \x00 \x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
    x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
    0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11U"\x873\xbaD\xcbD\xcbD\xcb3\xa8"\x87\x00B\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
    x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"\x87f\xff\xca\xff\xdb\xff\xca\xff\xeb\xff\xeb\xff\xdb\xff\xca\xff\x
    b9\xffU\xffD\xdb\x00B\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11D\xdcU\xff\xa9\xff\xfc
    \xff\xfc\xff\xfc\xff\xfc\xff\xfc\xff\xfc\xff\xfc\xff\xec\xffv\xffU\xffU\xfe"\x86\x00 \x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
    00\x00\x00\x00\x003\xbaU\xffU\xffU\xff\xb9\xff\xfc\xff\xb9\xff\x98\xffe\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfe\x11\x95\x000\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"fU\xff\xba\xff\xfc\xff\x98\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfeD\xfdD\xfdD\xfdU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfe3\xfc\x00r\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
    x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xdc\xa9\xff\xfc\xff\xfc\xff\xa8\xffU\xffD\xfe3\xfd3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfcD\xfdU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfd"\xc7\x00@\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"U\xff\xec\xff\xfc\xff\xfc\xffv\xffD\xfe3\xfc3\xfb"\xd7"\xd83\xfb3\xfc3\xfc3\xfcU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfe3\xea\x00`\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"vU\xff\xa9\xff\xfc\xff\xa9\xffU\xffD\xfd3\xea\x00\x90\x00\x80\x00p\x00p3\xfb3\xfc3\xfcU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfe
    3\xea\x00p\x000\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11TU\xfeU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfeU\xff"\xc6\x00p\x00P\x000\x00@3\xec3\xfc3\xfcU\xffU\xffU\xffD\
    xfe3\xfb\x00\x81\x000\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00RD\xfeU\xffU\xffU\xff3\xd9\x00\x81\x00P\x00 \x00 3\xbaD\xfd3\xfcD\xfeU\xff
    U\xffU\xffD\xfd"\xd8\x00p\x000\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00@\x00`\x00p\x00p\x00`\x00P\x000\x00!D\xdcD\xfe3\xfcD\xfeU\xf
    fU\xffU\xffD\xfe3\xfb\x00\xa1\x00`\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00 \x000\x000\x000\x00 \x11CU\xfeU\xffD\xf
    eU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfe3\xfb\x11\xc5\x00p\x00@\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x10\x
    00\x10\x11CU\xfeU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfd3\xfc\x11\xb3\x00p\x00P\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11D\xedU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xff3\xfc3\xfb\x11\xb3\x00p\x00P\x00 \x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
    0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"fU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfe3\xfb\x00\xb2\x00p\x00P\x00 \x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
    x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xccU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xff3\xfa"\xe9\x00\x80\x00P\x00 \x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
    x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xeeU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfd3\xfb\x11\xc5\x00`\x000\x
    00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003\xcaD\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3
    \xfc3\xfc3\xfb"\xe8\x00\x81\x00P\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
    00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x00a\x00\x81\x00\x91\x00\x91\x00\x91\x00\x91\x00\x81\x00P\x000\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
    x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11C"\x863\xca3\xda"\xc8\x11\x93\x00r\x00P\x000\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10U\xff\xa9\xff\xa8\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfdD\xfd\x00@\x00 \x00\x10\x00\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003\xcb\x98\xff\xfc\xff\xeb\x
    ffU\xffU\xffD\xfe3\xfc\x11\xa5\x000\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\xffe\xff\xb9\xffv\xffU\xffU\xffD\xfe3\xfc3\xea\x00P\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
    x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10U\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xffU\xff3\xfc3\xfc3\xfb\x00`\x000\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
    x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x103\xba3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc"\xd7\x00`\x000\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
    x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0003\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc\x00\x90\x00
    P\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x000
    3\xda3\xfc3\xfc3\xfc3\xea\x00\x90\x00`\x000\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x000\x00P\x00p\x00p\x00p\x00`\x00@\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00 \x000\x000\x000\x00 \x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
    00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\
    x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) tries to convert bytes to characters - is that really what you want to do? If you want to unpack the bytes to integers instead, have a look at the [struckt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) package.

Comment: Your Python code is odd: `byte` has no `at` method, so why can you write `array.at`? What’s the *actual* type of `array`? Also, your `try` statement is missing a `catch` block.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry forgot to delete try statement for the example. I am using Qbytearray that lets me use .at() statement

Comment: @MrFuppes I also tried tu use struct to convert gb and ar to uchar like the C++ code: <code>gb = struct.unpack("B", array.at(startByte + y * 2 * width + x * 2).encode())[0]
                ar = struct.unpack("B", array.at(startByte + y * 2 * width + x * 2 + 1).encode())[0]</code>

Comment: @MrFuppes No, unpacking isn’t what this code calls for, the byte array simply holds consecutive integers. `ord` isn’t necessary either though. Just subsetting into a byte array returns an integer.

Comment: @MrFuppes Sorry, I am not understanding your last answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you’ve posted doesn’t work because there are several errors, but none that would cause the error message you’re observing.

Here’s the code with those errors fixed. This should work (though it doesn’t work with the data you provided, since that is truncated):

```
def convertGBAR4444(array, width, height, startByte = 0):
    img = QImage(width, height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    img.fill(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0,0))

    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            gb = array[startByte + y * 2 * width + x * 2]
            ar = array[startByte + y * 2 * width + x * 2 + 1]
            #print(gb, ar)
            g = gb >> 4
            b = gb & 0xF
            a = ar >> 4
            r = ar & 0xF
            img.setPixel(x, y, qRgba(r * 0x11, g * 0x11, b * 0x11, a * 0x11))
    return img
```

Comment: Getting this error now `g = gb >> 4
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'bytes' and 'int'`?

Comment: making the result ' ord() ' worked and made the image perfectly. Thank you!!!